# Class Constructor Overload not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
#include <iostream>

class Car{
public:
    Car(float newSpeed = 0, double newHP = 100);

protected:
    double HP;

private:
    float speed;
};



Car::Car(float newSpeed, double newHP)
{
    speed = newSpeed;
    HP = newHP;
}

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Car car(10, 100);
    return(0);
}
```

The above code does not compile with an error saying: "1>c:\users\aaron\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ass3\ass3\main.cpp(9): error C2661: 'Car::Car' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments"

I am not sure why.  I first tried this with default arguments to the Car constructor

```
Car::Car(float newSpeed = 0, double newHP = 100);
```

but that did not work either.

I have been working on this for 3 days now.  any help is much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Edit:  suggestions below

Comment: I copied it from visual studio.  I promise it is my real code.

Comment: Did you also get a warning about `void main()`? Whatever is running this most likely expects a return value.

Comment: No error for the un-matched `ifndef`? Yes, yes, copy-paste error, but you broke my trust saying this is the real code...

Comment: You're missing an `#endif` in car.h. After fixing that, changing `main`'s return type to `Int` and commenting out the import of `sports_car.h`, it compiles fine.

Comment: No not at all. I always use void main.  This is the whole program. Running in windows.

Comment: But `main`'s return type _must_ be `int` per the standard (in hosted implementations).

Comment: @ngong0, Windows expects a value back when running your program. Other programs might even rely on it. If you're living in Windows's house, follow Windows's rules, which do happen to be in the standard. Stroustrup's FAQ has the reference: http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: I performed the suggestions, and still get a compile error that there is no overload taking 2 arguments for Car::Car.

Comment: Since the answer got removed, I'll post it here: The following is the simplest exact form of your described error, and it compiles: http://liveworkspace.org/code/fdb7c943aaee093320b97851e937b086. The only explanation I can think of right now is that you're using an outdated version of your header. Also, after the whole main return type thing, the standard also says `main` will implicitly return 0 if no return value is specified. At least you can still save the line with the return statement, so it's actually one less character in total than using `void main()`.

Comment: The compiler wants me to give no arguments when declaring my Car class.  I want to be able to do either.

Comment: @Febi, `10.0` is a `double`. There are also implicit conversions from `int` to `float`, as well as `int` to `double`, so it should compile fine, as it does in my linked test.

Comment: @Febi I tried that.  Thanks though.

Comment: Use Dev-C++ , everything will compile :)

Comment: I am going to try compiling with MinGW once it is finished installing. I doubt it is a Visual Studio problem though.

Comment: Your code compiles cleanly here using Visual C++ 2010 and warning level `/W4`. The problem is specific to your computer.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I am on VS 2010 ultimate. Windows 7 64-bit.  how can this be computer specific?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem using VS 2010 and Windows 7 64-bit. Possibly your installation is corrupted or you have some bad project setting. Have you tried creating a new Project from scratch and adding your code?

Comment: I will try that now.
Edit:  did not work.

Comment: @ngong0, The one you had of default arguments should work as well as long as the default arguments are in the declaration and not in the definition. Consider [this example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/23215ecb8bb2a27a73e56e377a013c8f).

Comment: @chris Correct.  That is how I had it. It seems to completely ignore all constructors that have arguments.

Comment: Try putting ALL the code in one file to make sure you aren't getting outdated includes.

Comment: I tried putting all code in one file, and still "no overloaded function takes 2 arguments"

Comment: Condensed down.  still does not compile.

Comment: @ngong0, What you posted has no `(float, double)` constructor.

Comment: Whoops.  When I copied it to a single file i didn't copy that function.  It does compile as a single file.

Comment: So.  If there is a car.h lingering on my computer somewhere.  Should I just rename my header file?

Comment: @ngong0, Well, it's not the problem if it still happens in the single-file test. It's compiling fine for me under VS2010 Express.

Comment: What I have posted now works in single file.

Comment: When I did the initial copy to the single file,  I missed the overloaded constructor.  After correcting that it works in single file.  Now i just need to figure out what is going on with the multi-file.

Comment: @ngong0, Yeah, try a new project with a different set of names.

Comment: Everything seems to be working.  Thank you guys/girls so much!!  You are awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Wild guess warning)**

Based on all your descriptions in the comments, this looks like a situation where you have **another car.h file** somewhere on your computer.  And the compiler is finding that one.

Since you're in Windows, it may also be Car.h or CAR.H, etc.

**Edit**

With no clear resolution, *"I am going to call this solved. Thank you for all your help. – ngong0"*.

Voting to close.

Comment: Yeah, I had a guess about an outdated version being used in the comments. It's not seeming too unlikely at this point. To that end, @OP, check the include directories carefully.

Comment: Yes, but #include with quotes should look only in the current directory.

Comment: @ngong0, It can move to the <> ones as well, but I think it's supposed to only go to those after not finding it in the current directory.

Comment: If the header file is outdated, is there some way to update it?  I have tried cleaning and rebuilding,  Moving all files to a different project in a different folder.

Comment: @ngong0 VisualC++ will follow these rules: _"[quoted] form instructs the preprocessor to look for include files in the same directory of the file that contains the #include statement, and then in the directories of any files that include (#include) that file. The preprocessor then searches along the path specified by the /I compiler option, then along paths specified by the INCLUDE environment variable."_

Comment: Even with all code in one file, and no include of files I have created still the same issue.

Comment: @DrewDormann, Don't worry, my comment was even only about an outdated version, but there could indeed be another, possibly more random, file being found. And it looks like it can't even be that.

Comment: @ngong0 that's a big clue.  Can you edit your question to reflect that ?  Paste the one file exactly as it is.

Comment: @ngong0 better still, if you remove all the unused member functions and it still doesn't compile, can you paste **that**?  The smallest example makes this better for everyone involved.

Comment: @DrewDormann, Good point, the singular file is probably better than the three separate files anyway. I would get rid of what's here if the error is still in what you post.

Comment: @ngong Please paste the correct error that you get now.

Comment: I do not get an error in my single file corrected code.

Comment: @ngong0 Then it's time to search your computer for files named "car.h".  Windows has a utility for that.

Comment: I renamed the file to my_car.h and the same issue.

Comment: @ngong0 We're no longer talking about the program described in your question then.  Post the simplest possible program that shows your problem and people will be able to help you.  According to your comments, **the program in your question does not cause the error in your question**.

Comment: I am going to call this solved.  Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

if this is your ctor

Car();

then you will not succeed with giving two arguments

you need to create a constructor that takes two arguments

class Car{
public:
    Car(int HP, float speed);

Comment: The funny thing is that this ctor existed in the previous code.